# How do modulations depend on transmission media?

Tags: communication, network, telecommunications

or how is transmission media affected by modulation? Is there any relationship?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transmission medium is the transmission medium, whether it's coaxial cable, free space, or whatever.

You'll choose a carrier signal and a modulation method to suit the medium, and the requirements of the transmission.

For instance, in free space, requiring good SNR without error correction, you might choose wideband FM for audio transmission, as it has a high tolerance from impulsive noise.

If you expect heavy multipath, or you want to use geographically separated transmitters on a common frequency, and you have plenty of processing power available, you'll choose OFDM.